# How does a residential grid-tied solar system work exactly?

Tags: power, inverter, power-engineering, solar-energy

Ok.. so I know how solar panels are connected to a combiner box & tied into a charge controller/inverter.  I also know that the AC from the inverter must be in phase with the line/mains power.

**What I would like to know is the following:**

1. Exactly how much voltage (above the line voltage) must the inverter output be in order to cause current to flow out to the grid?
2. On a 100A mains line, how much current could be output to the grid (assuming your solar array had slightly more net capacity than your line is capable of carrying & what would happen to the excess power from your solar system if it could not be sent out to the grid, due to it being higher than the mains line is rated to carry?
3. What would be the difference in an oscilloscope trace if I viewed the output from the solar system when it is grid-tied vs the normal mains trace on the oscilloscope if the grid-tie was not connected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) The inverter output will be exactly the line voltage, **having raised the (local) line voltage according to the source impedance of the supply line and the current developed** As the inverter is connected to the line, its output is the (locally measured) line voltage by definition. The "meter spins backwards" when generation exceeds use, because it senses the current direction. Often there would be separate meters for consumption and generation.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fk0S8Q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is a residential distribution network, your house is No.2, the third from the pole transformer and the only one with solar power. Currently it's in shadow, so the line voltage reduces slightly further from the pole, and the last house (No.3) sees 109V.

When the sun comes out, the line voltage at the pole remains 115V, but your local line voltage also becomes 115V.

No. 1 is now fed from both sides and it's line will rise from 113V to 114V, and No.3 is still 2V below your line voltage, now seeing 113V.

Weather  Line    No.1   No.2   No.3
Cloudy   115V    113V   111V   109V
Sunny    115V    114V   115V   113V

(2) Where are you and what connection regime are you in? If you're in the UK and conforming to the G83/2 standard for a single phase residential connection, the answer is up to 16A. (Higher output is allowed on a separate standard, G59/2 for 3 phase connections). Any excess power is simply not drawn from the panel (assuming this is a grid tie system with no local storage)

None of this applies outside the UK.

(3) Pretty much nothing visible, maybe a very slightly higher voltage and marginally cleaner waveshape (assuming your inverter is legal and conforms to the applicable standards, including harmonic distortion.

---

The [G83/2 specification](https://www.ofgem.gov.uk/ofgem-publications/52354/er-g83-2-v5-master-09-07-12-inc-ofgem-comments-clean-version.pdf) illustrates the requirements for protection against overvoltage, out of tolerance frequency and waveform shape - and the all-important consideration of disconnecting immediately if the grid fails, to prevent electrocuting the engineers trying to repair it!

[Here's an article on the rules in California](http://www.greentechmedia.com/articles/read/california-closes-in-on-smart-solar-inverter-rules) to get you started on the US standards - which may well vary from State to State.

Grid regulation is a topic in itself - it isn't automatic, someone monitors it and adds or removes generation capacity to keep its parameters (voltage and frequency) within limits.

One characteristic of traditional (spinning metal) generators is that as you load them, they slow down a little, which reduces their output voltage and their contribution to the grid - transferring their load to others, which slow down in turn - arriving at a concensus on the actual mains frequency. You can watch this process [in the UK in real time here](http://www.gridwatch.templar.co.uk/). At the moment, it's reading 50.007Hz, so there's no need for additional capacity, but if it falls to 49.9Hz, phone calls will be made and some other power source will be turned on...

The importance of this for grid tie inverters is the way they can [affect demand and power flows in the short term](http://www.greentechmedia.com/articles/read/the-great-solar-smart-grid-challenge) in unpredictable ways, taht the grid isn't currently designed for.

Comment: 1.  I'm in the USA.  Residential power is 2 x 120V lines that are in phase.  What is 'startup voltage'?  I'm asking about the output power of the inverter to the grid.  2.  Why such a low current flow (i.e. 16A) to the grid in the UK?  3.  So how does current get sent out to the grid if the voltage isn't higher? And how is the meter spun in reverse if the output V isn't higher than the the incoming line current?

Comment: Then you'll have to find your local code as revised for distributed generation. The 16A limit is per household, to limit instability on residential grid systems. If several houses backfed 100A, you'd trip the neighbourhood without a major system redesign. Higher power connections require more infrastructure costs that don't exactly come under the "residential" tag.

Comment: Is the 16A limit in the UK per hour?

Comment: Amps are a continuous, instantaneous measure: one coulomb per second = one amp.

Comment: Current is a rate, so 16A per hour is nonsense.

Comment: Ok, look at it from a power (Watts) standpoint then, please.  What happens to the V & A at the grid connection as power flows from the line into the system vs when generated power flows in the reverse direction.  One or both of the V or A has to change for the meter to change directions, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, as explained in the answer, the current changes direction.

Comment: Exactly - imagine measuring in the morning; to start with Vhouse < Vgrid by a tiny amount and A is flowing in. As the power from the panels increase A tends to zero, at which point Vhouse = Vgrid; then A goes "negative" (ie in the other direction) and Vhouse > Vgrid by a tiny amount.

Comment: @pjc50 - How much is that 'tiny amount' when Vhouse > Vgrid & what does that translate to in Watts out?

Comment: Depends on the resistance of the wire between the two points at which you choose to measure Vhouse and Vgrid. Probably millivolts. Watts out is V * A as measured at the meter, integrated over time into kWh used on your bill.

Comment: Wouldn't the loading of the line by utility customers decrease the Vgrid & thus cause your Vhouse output to cause more Watts to flow to the grid (assuming your system had the ability to output sufficient power to try to up the decreased Vgrid caused by loading?

Comment: @Brian Drummond - That's a useful schematic & good explanation.  Based on that information, it would seem reasonable that the utility company would adjust their generation based on how much they measured on the line.  Thus if I and multiple other grid-tied solar users were to generate most of the power for that subnet then the utility company could considerably scale back their power generation.  Is that correct?

Comment: The control system operates the other way round: the solar inverter has a certain power available to it, and is trying to drive Vhouse as high as possible. Your final statement about offsetting power generation is correct and absolutely the point of the whole system.

Comment: Up to break-even on a subnet, that,s probably true. Beyond that point, that's way over-simplistic. They just don't have that level of control over every subnet ... today. Read some of the accounts of grid instability when something small trips (because your pole transformer went over-voltage), overloading something else, and shutting down the whole West Coast for hours. You *could* redesign the whole distribution to overcome these problems, but that costs money and takes time.

Comment: (obviously within limits on Vhouse - going above say 10% of normal grid voltage ought to trip a safety cut-out!)

Comment: Is the grid system automatically adjusted for varying loads & how much can a generator be throttled before it shutdown or started up (depending on what the case may be?

Comment: @pjc50 - good point on the need for protection! Added a reference to the specification applicable in the UK. Adding a bit on grid regulation too.

Comment: Grid system adjustment is a mix of automatic and manual. "How much" depends on the specific generator. Have a look at http://gridwatch.templar.co.uk/ - the UK has quite a lot of coal-fired generation that's only used in winter nights.

Comment: (oh, a little extra detail: most power plants require power to start and run! Losing power across the whole grid requires a multi-day recovery process called "black start".)

Comment: pjc50 - don't make this about race... jk ;)

Comment: I think we've shot his hog pretty hard, fellas!  Now all I have to do is flip a coin to decide who to give my vote to... Can I select upvotes for both of your answers or just 1 of you?

Comment: You can upvote as many answers as you want, but only select one as "correct" even if both are.

Comment: Ok.  I guess I'll have to give you each an up vote for your answers & you the edge for your drawing & more thorough explanation--although both of you were quite helpful.  Thanks to both of you for helping me to understand better!

Comment: +1 lots of interesting details. Don't know if you saw that essentially ALL of South Australia went down a few days ago. Storm damage triggered and ... . Thy seem to have it mostly restored now. Mostly.

Comment: @DIYser, Re: your 1st comment: Actually, in the US most residential customers get 240/120 where you have 2 lines of 120VAC which are 180° out of phase, not in phase. The voltage between those two lines is 240VAC (nominal) with each line being 120VAC (nominal) to neutral/ground. If the lines were in phase then there would be no voltage between the two. This allows the use of 240VAC for those applications where a larger power draw is needed (e.g. electric stoves, clothes dryers, central heat) while the two legs of 120VAC are used independently (i.e. returning to neutral) for most other circuits.

Comment: What if you are the only house on your transformer?  Or all the neighbors on the transformer have solar and have excess power available?  Can you feed excess power back into the grid by stepping it up through the transformer, or can you only supply it on your side of the transformer?

Comment: @Makyen - re " If the lines were in phase then there would be no voltage between the two."  Don't they need to be in phase for the voltages to combine to get 240V (i.e. 120V+120V)?  If they were out-of-phase, the wave peaks would cancel each & produce 0V.  For comparison, 3 phase power has 3 phases that are 120 degree to each other & therefore provide peaks at different time to get max power for an electrical device.

Comment: @Brian Drummond - If I had a PV system that was designed to output a net 5 kWs (exactly) & I powered off every device in my home & the skys were completely clear all day on an optimal summer day & we assume my system can legally output a max 16A@125V=4kW to the grid, would my electric watt meter indicate -4 kwh after 1 hour or something else? Also, what would happen to the extra 1 kW that my PV system generated?

Comment: @DIYser, 240/120: two 120VAC (nominal to gnd/neutral) legs are 180° out-of-phase with each other, not in-phase. In-phase would mean both are positive(rel to gnd) at the same time (resulting in 0VAC between them). 180° out-of-phase means that when one leg is positive(rel to gnd), the other is negative (resulting in 240VAC *between* the legs). If we took the instantaneous numeric value of the voltage of each leg relative to ground and added them, then yes, they would be zero (nominally). But delivering power is based on the *difference* between the legs, not their numeric sum relative to ground.

Comment: @Makyen - I've seen a graph of one line of 240/120Vac service in the US and the +peak is ~+176V & the -peak is ~-176V.  If line 1 is 180 degress out of phase with line 2, then how would one combine them to get 240V without the phases canceling each other out?  I would expect an o-scope with the right test probe on it to show a graph with a + & - peak of ~350V.  What am I not understanding or misunderstanding. Keep in mind that I know exactly what you have stated, but I don't see how an oscope would show the proper V if the line phases are 180 degrees out of phase.

Comment: @DIYser, 240VAC and 120VAC are RMS values, not peak-to-peak. The peak-to-peak numbers you state are consistent with 240VAC (RMS) and 120VAC (RMS), which are 679V and 339V (peak-to-peak, all values nominal). You are thinking canceling when what we really care about is the *difference* between the voltages, not adding the two voltages relative to some arbitrary reference (ground). The difference between two sine waves 180° out-of-phase results in the voltages adding, not subtracting. Plotted, the difference between the two, is the same as a sine wave with 2* the amplitude of one of the waves.

Comment: @Makyen -- That makes sense.  Thanks for the clarification!  Can you answer the last question (above) that I asked Brian Drummond?

Comment: @DIYser, Quite a bit of this chain of comments deserves to be separate Questions and Answers. However, the basics of the one you reference is easy: The extra power goes the same place as the significant majority of the solar energy hitting the PV cell (cells are significantly <30% efficient): heat at the PV (note: a portion of solar radiation is reflected, not absorbed). The PV cell sets up a DC potential difference, it does not force the electric power to be used. Where *exactly* portions of that power dissipate would depend on the design of your system, but most should be at the PV cells.

Comment: @Makyen - when I stated net 5kW, I was referring to actual power that the PV system is designed to output--not 5kW of energy striking the panels.  For example, if the output of the PV array was rated for 7.2 kW but under actual optimal conditions generated 5 kW.  If the legal limit for my system permitted only 4 kW to be exported to the grid (let's say controlled by my equip), then would 4 kWh be uploaded to the grid in 1 hr & the rest be dissipated as heat within the pv panels or other componets within my local system that could dissipate the extra energy?

Comment: @DIYser, What actually happens with the power is up to the design of the system. I had assumed the system would be designed (or parameters set) such that it would never output to the grid over the amount that you were legally permitted. If it was not set that way then additional power might go out on the grid (depends on system). Any excess power available at the array which was not consumed by you, or sent out to the grid, would primarily end up as heat within the PV cells which would dissipate to the air (basically, like anything else that is sitting out in the sun).

Answer (score 2):

1) To reason about this, consider applying ohm's law to the line leading into your house. It's not possible for the voltage to be higher on the house side than the grid size by more than an amount determined by the resistance of the wire, which is going to be very small. Probably tens to hundreds of milivolts.

2) Current flow is limited by power output. I have a 3.8kW solar system in the UK which outputs up to the 16A mentioned in the other comment. It occupies my entire roof, and is just below the 4kW limit to which a different permitting and feed-in-tariff regime applies at which point it would be an "industrial" system.

100A on a US 110V system would be 11kW, quite a substantial system costing in the region of $15k.

Obviously no permitting regime is going to let you put a >100A output system on a 100A line as that would melt the line.

3) Hard to tell, although I expect it would be cleaner. You might be able to pick up a harmonic output from the inverter, showing as a slight ripple in the sine wave. It's certainly obliged to be the same frequency and RMS voltage.

Edit: I have a grid-tie system in the UK, so can't really speak about US grid or code matters.

Comment: The US system is normally a pair of 110V lines in antiphase (i.e. a centre-tapped 220V system) so 11kw would be 50A on each leg, otherwise there'd be a serious imbalance.

Comment: Actually when I measure the voltage of each line, it shows 120V to 125V until lots of users load the line--then the voltage decreases to from 117 to 120V.  I never have understood why some people refer to it as 110V--I've never ever seen 110V on any line that I've ever measured.

Comment: No idea, it's probably some sort of cultural relic. It looks like the official standard is 120V.

Comment: In my experience, it is rare to see 120VAC residential service delivery in the US. Usually, it's three-wire, single phase, grounded (also known as "split-phase") 240VAC, with some attempt to balance the wall outlets. (Even my pump house, which is on a separate system from the residence, gets split-phase service.) I can only imagine what might happen if 100A were attempted on just one half of that split-phase transformer's secondary.

Comment: @jonk - my power line is overhead.  It has 2 copper wires & one high tension wire that the copper lines run along.  The main breaker is 100A & the 2 copper bus bars each have 120+VAC on them most of the day.  I've never looked at them on an oscilloscope, however I've been told by utility personnel that both lines are in phase. I thought that was standard residential wiring in the USA. I've never seen line voltage lower than 115VAC any place that I've measured the voltage (which includes multiple US states).  Just added this blurb for further clarification.

Comment: @DIYser you'll find they aren't in phase, but 180 degrees apart. That lets you use both together for a 220/240V appliance... be careful with that scope though!

Comment: @Brian Drummond - Thanks for that info, I'll have to scope it one day!

Comment: @DIYser Brian is right. 120VAC requires too much current for an oven (up to 8kW or so) or a stove-top (up to 5kW or so.) Water heaters and dryers are other commonly high-use devices, as well. So 240VAC service is useful to cut down on the amount of copper required. Too many people require an oven in their homes, which is why I said it is rare to see residential 120VAC.

Comment: @DIYser The usual result of trying to use a regular oscilloscope on the mains is (at best) the ground lead blown off. Shock is possible and there was a sad story here from a person that used a USB scope thing on the mains and fried not only the box but also their entire PC.

Comment: >100A on a 100A line will not melt the line for sensible overloads (as I know you know) but will cause more voltage drop and losses than desirable. (eg 200A = 4 x nomina max losses, still only 'warm' if that). I have two (real) 230 VAC phase feed here. Both are notionally rated below currently desired conductor weight due to historical reasons but my measured line impedance is extremely low (according to power company tests).

Comment: @Russell McMahon - what is the amp rating of your 230 VAC lines (if you had properly sized conductors)?  What size are your conductors & how much current can they safely handle?

Comment: @DIYser I've lived here for ~= 30 years. The man 2 before me had 3 phase power and a small factory in the back yard. Plastic moulder et al. I never saw it. When I bought it it had 2 phase power. Never had problems for 20-25 years with usual domestic and light commercial use. About ?5? years ago it blew the pole fuse - quite possibly due to corrosion/happenstance. Lineman said the conductors were too small for fuse (60A?) and put in a smaller one. Which of course blew within months. They put in an original sized one and in process of certifying do impedance test which was at the low end ...

Comment: ... of the scale. I forget the figure but it suggested a potential failt current of humungous. I have been informally and verbally advised that feed needs upsizing but 30 years of use by me and probably 50 + overall, plus low Z and no problems suggest that the original certifier was both happy and correct. || "Proper" I actually know not but 60A x 2 phases would be very adequate for my use.